# Java Swing repaint and revalidate not always working

Tags: java, swing, validation, layout, repaint

I have a problem with swing and updating a JPanel with few buttons. Sometimes I need to delete or add or even modify some buttons. I have created a routine to do that, with few dialogs and messagebox. The fact is that sometimes (randomly) the JPanel don't refresh correctly (it don't delete the button as requested or even it not add it). If I call a second time the refresh routine (I call the dialog to add a button and then click exit without adding anythin) all go well. I can't find out why, I think it's about timing and the time that needs each repaint or revalidate method to be effective, this consideration is because I tried to debug the program (with eclipse and few breakpoints) and during debug it always refresh correctly.

Here is some code (simplified).

```
// This method is used when first creating the GUI (the removeAll obviously remove nothing
// I call the revalidate because I re-add the buttons, and I call repaint to have the
// JPanel itself repainted.

public static void repaintServices() {
    //services is a JPanel
    services.removeAll();
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("SERVIZI");

    services.add(lbl);
    services.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));

    // ########## SERVICES BUTTONS
    Database.connect();
    ArrayList<Service> s = Database.listServices();
    JPanel btt = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        JButton b = new JButton(s.get(i).getName().toUpperCase());
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            btt = new JPanel();
            btt.setLayout(new BoxLayout(btt, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
            services.add(btt);
            services.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
            btt.add(b);
        } else {
            btt.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
            btt.add(b);
        }
    }
    Database.disconnect();
    // ########## END SERVICES BUTTONS

    services.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

    services.revalidate();
    services.repaint();
}
```

This is where I modify the database (and so the button list)

```
LOG.finest("User ask to add a new Service");

ArrayList<String> result = GUI.showServiceDialog();
if (result.size() > 0) {
    if (!"".equals(result.get(0))) {
        String name = result.get(0);

        Database.connect();
        if (Database.addService(name, price, cadence)) {
            GUI.showMessage("Servizio aggiunto correttamente");
        GUI.repaintServices();
        }
        Database.disconnect();
    } else {
        GUI.showErrorMessage("All field necessary!\nNew Service NOT added");
        return;
    }
}else {
    return;
}
```

This is the metod used to get the values inserted by the user (uses a custom modal dialog box)

```
public static ArrayList<String> showServiceDialog() {
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    JTextField name = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField price = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField cadence = new JTextField(4);

    // NOT USEFUL STUFF, just adding some components. JUMP DOWN TO.....
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    JPanel pp = new JPanel();
    pp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pp, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    pp.add(new JLabel("Nome:"));
    pp.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    pp.add(name);

    p.add(pp);
    p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10)); // a spacer

    pp = new JPanel();
    pp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pp, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    pp.add(new JLabel("Prezzo:"));
    pp.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    pp.add(price);
    pp.add(new JLabel("€"));
    pp.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
    pp.add(new JLabel("Frequenza:"));
    pp.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    pp.add(cadence);

    p.add(pp);
    p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));

    // .... HERE, following the interesting part.

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(window, p, "Inserisci i dati del nuovo servizio", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        ret.add(name.getText());
        ret.add(price.getText());
        ret.add(cadence.getText());
    }
    return ret;

}
```

I have some other methods like delete, edit etc etc but the problem (not refreshing correct) is randomly with each of this method, I posted the simplest part i have.

any Idea?
(I have the same problem also with other part of the GUI like comboBoxes or listBoxes, the GUI is started with SwingUtilities.invokeLater)

HERE some SSCCE code, the problem occurs doing:
ADD, ADD, REMOVE, ADD

the adds after a remove do not refresh correctly (sometimes, sometimes randomly, as I said). (without touching any other thing). I hope the code Is clear enough and short enough, I removed the database that seems not to be involved.

```
package it.kApps;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RevalidateRepaintTry {

private static JPanel   services;
private static ArrayList<String>    s;

public RevalidateRepaintTry() {
    s = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add("btt1");
    s.add("btt2");
    JFrame main = new JFrame();
    main.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(main.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    services = new JPanel();
    repaintServices();
    JButton b = new JButton("ADD");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            String add = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("insert new");
            s.add(add);
            repaintServices();
        }
    });
    JButton bb = new JButton("DEL");
    bb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            s.remove(s.size() - 1);
            repaintServices();
        }
    });
    main.add(services);
    main.add(b);
    main.add(bb);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.pack();
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new RevalidateRepaintTry();
        }
    });

}

public static void repaintServices() {
    // services is a JPanel
    services.removeAll();
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("SERVIZI");

    services.add(lbl);
    services.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));

    // ########## SERVICES BUTTONS
    JPanel btt = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        JButton b = new JButton(s.get(i));
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            btt = new JPanel();
            btt.setLayout(new BoxLayout(btt, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
            services.add(btt);
            services.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
            btt.add(b);
        } else {
            btt.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
            btt.add(b);
        }
    }
    // ########## END SERVICES BUTTONS

    services.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

    services.revalidate();
    services.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: *"I posted the simplest part i have."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: thankyou for the answer, the problem is that I can't write something simple, because if simple there are no problem with refreshing. By the way, I am trying !

Comment: I never instructed you to write anything 'simple'?  Did you actually read the link, or are you just guessing?

Comment: yep, I can surely post all the code but it isn't short, and the problem is that I use an external jar (database). Any tip?

Comment: *"Any tip?"*  Yeah, plenty of them.  I concentrated them in that article since a comment is too small for them.  *"it isn't short"*  Make it short.  That snippet has 3 label/textfield combos.  Drop it to two.  *"use an external jar (database)"* Hard-code some data in the source.

Comment: 1. Makes sure all update occur only in the EDT, 2. call `invaildate`, `revalidate`, `repaint`

Comment: got it, Edited the question with some compiling, working code. just try what I suggest above the code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer from the javadoc of removeAll() <code>This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy</code> so the panel should be invalidated each time I call repaintServices()

Comment: @Gianmarco and you've tried it?

Comment: @Gianmarco Works fine for me :P - One problem I did have is the window did not resize (as I would expect it not to), which means that some of buttons where layout in an area of the panel that wasn't visible

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, tried many times, always the same problem. Maybe is the OS? I have mac osx 10.7.5 with java 7. I tried before to post it to be sure that there was the problem. For the resize is normal, because I didn't manage anything about the graphics, just resize it to be big with the mouse. I tried (in the same run) many times, sometimes the problem occurs very soon (1 add 1 remove) sometimes it takes ten or more adds and removes. It's random

Comment: @Gianmarco Works fine on my Mac (Lion)

Comment: Just wait few moments, I try to upload on youtube a video of the problem.

Comment: http://youtu.be/b26uP9QebDA here is the video, you can see the problem 2 times. (one about second 23 and one at the end)

Comment: WOOOOO the video, don't show what I really saw..... ! the video is perfect, as if The problem don't exists...... strange...

Comment: http://youtu.be/uLiIzvPPhhI here the right video showing the problem. what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling it's a problem with the layout manager...

Personally, I'd start out by using a different layout manager.

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, which has a awesome side effect of not "wrapping" components the expand beyond the horizontal width of the parent container.

While I understand that `Box` can be used with other layout managers, it was designed to work with `BoxLayout`, so I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work the way you wanted.

```
public class RevalidateRepaintTry {

    private static JPanel services;
    private static ArrayList<String> s;

    public RevalidateRepaintTry() {
        s = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.add("btt1");
        s.add("btt2");
        JFrame main = new JFrame();
        main.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(main.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        services = new JPanel();
        repaintServices();
        JButton b = new JButton("ADD");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String add = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("insert new");
                s.add(add);
                repaintServices();
            }

        });
        JButton bb = new JButton("DEL");
        bb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                s.remove(s.size() - 1);
                repaintServices();
            }

        });
        main.add(services);
        main.add(b);
        main.add(bb);
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.pack();
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RevalidateRepaintTry();
            }

        });

    }

    public static void repaintServices() {
        // services is a JPanel
        services.removeAll();
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("SERVIZI");

        JPanel view = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(view);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        view.add(lbl, gbc);

        // ########## SERVICES BUTTONS
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton(s.get(i));
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                gbc.gridy++;
                gbc.gridx = 0;
            } else {
                gbc.gridx++;
            }
            view.add(b, gbc);
        }
        // ########## END SERVICES BUTTONS

        view.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        services.add(scroll);

        services.revalidate();
        services.repaint();
    }
}
```

Note, I threw in a `JScrollPane`, it's probably not required

Comment: Argh, when I read your answer I almost fainted, I have all the program with BoxLayout and can be almost impossible to change to GridBag... So I tried your sscce and fortunately (or unfortunately because we don't have yet a solution) I have the same problem.

Comment: I've test both the original code and my code on Mac OS Lion under JDK 7 (update) 7 without issue. I suspect that there is something going on within your compound layout which doesn't seem to be appearing here.  Try this. Add a border to the services pane (something line a `LineBorder`) and/or set the background of the services pane.  This will allow you to monitor to see if the panel is been layout correctly.  If that doesn't work, try resizing the frame to see if it forces a layout

Comment: yep, without trying I know that even just clicking on the panel or resizing the frame all goes well, it's something that I can't explain, I tried all the things you said but sometimes the panel seems only not to refresh. But I know (via debug) that the methods are correctly called. Did you see the video? Think about that with quicktime recording tool I could not see any error (after) while I was actually seeing it.

Comment: all components created by Box are useable anywhere - no magic involved, just components with special sizing hints :-) @Gianmarco your SSCCE worksforme and I see not much a reason that it blows in your context, neither OS nor LAF should matter. Are you sure you are running _that exact example_ in your video? As an aside: you really want to add a new btt every three buttons (has no effect, just feels like a possible oversight)?

Comment: 100% sure that is the exact example in the video, no i do not really want to add a btt every 3, but sometimes it happens the first time. And if I give the program to non-programmer user maybe he cant misunderstood the problem and add once again the button or something similar